# Read Bytes Into Stream One Page At A Time C#

Tags: c#

I have broken down a file into pages on a download. Now I want to reconstruct the file pages in order to save the entire document to a location in the format of the page extensions. How do I do this? Here is code I started with to read a one page file but it isn't working for a multipage one. When I open the output file its says it cannot open because it is "damaged"? How can I be certain this code eventhough its not throwing any exceptions is reconstructing the file correctly?

Is it because I am not setting the offset correctly? My offset is always at 0

```
foreach (IContentTransfer contentelement in doc.ContentElements)
{
    if (this.SuspendProcess)
        return ErroredRecords;
    Stream inStream = contentelement.AccessContentStream();
    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[inStream.Length];

    string ext = Path.GetExtension(contentelement.RetrievalName);

    String outPath = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}.{3}", BatchInfo.RootFolder, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, docInfo.FileNamePrefix, ext);
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(outPath, FileMode.Append);
    fileStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on "it isn't working"?

Comment: How isn't it working? Does your code throw exceptions? Do you not get the expected result and then what do you get?

Comment: What did you think [FileMode.CreateNew](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=VS.110).aspx) meant? Try `Append`.

Comment: the code is not setup to take each content element and contruct it into the origonal entire document

Comment: `When I open the output file its says it cannot open because it is "damaged"?` when you open it where? Who says it's damaged? What is your file in the first place? How did you break it into pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `doc.ContentElements` is where you are getting your "pages" from, then all you need to do is iterate over that and read in each "page", then `Append` it your output file. The only line that should need changing is here:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(outPath, FileMode.CreateNew);
```

To this:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(outPath, FileMode.Append);
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=VS.110).aspx) for the `Append` enum value (emphasis mine):

> **Opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or creates a new file**. This requires FileIOPermissionAccess.Append permission. FileMode.Append can be used only in conjunction with FileAccess.Write. Trying to seek to a position before the end of the file throws an IOException exception, and any attempt to read fails and throws a NotSupportedException exception.

So this mode will create a new file if it doesn't already exist, or add content to an existing file. `CreateNew` will always try to create a new file or throw an exception if the file already exists.

Comment: When I try to open the file and view it says its "damaged" How can I be certain this code eventhough its not throwing any exceptions is reconstructing the file correctly?

Comment: @nlstack01: Open the file where? Being damaged may be a problem with how you cut the file up in the first place and tried to reconstruct it. We don't have enough context to really speculate.

Comment: When I am writing the file don't I have to change the offset or does it not matter? Its always at 0 in my code

Comment: @nlstack01: From what I quoted above: `seeks to the end of the file`

Answer (score 1):

You `foreach` loop will either be overwriting the file each time or creating individual files instead of one complete file, I can't tell which. The reason is that you using `FileMode.CreateNew` when creating the output `FileStream` object.

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(outPath, FileMode.CreateNew);
```

Replacing this with `FileMode.Append` should solve your problem as long as the file path is the same for each iteration of the loop.

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(outPath, FileMode.Append);
```

Comment: Actually it shouldn't overwrite. `CreateNew` will throw an exception if the file already exists, so the OP's code should throw rather than overwrite.

Comment: Yes that is true, but the OP did not say it was not throwing an exception, he just said "it isn't working"

Comment: When I try to open the file and view it says its "damaged" How can I be certain this code eventhough its not throwing any exceptions is reconstructing the file correctly?